# can't run command `python -m ensurepip` without getting segment fault error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I compiled openssl and python on a system:

- OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017'
- Python 2.7.12 (default, Aug  9 2017, 19:48:22)

I keep getting segment fault when i try to add pip:

```
python -m ensurepip
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail? Especially what commands did you use exactly.

Comment: Minor edits for legibility.

Comment: What OS are you on? What compiler did you use to build Python? Have you tried making a debug build and debugging the segfault?